# Rails 6 controller test failure: expect(CreatesProject).to have_received(:new).with({name: "Runway", task_string: "start something:2"})

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to run the controller test in the Rails application.

### Controller code

Here is the code for controller test (`/app/controllers/projects_controller.rb`):

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  ## START: show
  def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {}
      format.js { render json: @project.as_json(root: true, include: :tasks) }
    end
  end
  ## END: show

  def new
    @project = Project.new
  end

  def index
    @projects = Project.all
  end

  ## START: create
  def create
    @workflow = CreatesProject.new(
      name: params[:project][:name],
      task_string: params[:project][:tasks])
    @workflow.create
    if @workflow.success?
      redirect_to projects_path
    else
      @project = @workflow.project
      render :new
    end
  end
  ## END: create
end
```

### Controller Test

Here is the test where the terminal is showing the error (`/spec/controllers/projects_controller_spec`):

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe ProjectsController, type: :controller do

  describe "create" do
    it "calls the workflow with parameters" do
      workflow = instance_spy(CreatesProject, success?: true)
      allow(CreatesProject).to receive(:new).and_return(workflow)
      post :create,
        params: {project: {name: "Runway", tasks: "start something:2"}}
      expect(CreatesProject).to have_received(:new)
        .with({name: "Runway", task_string: "start something:2"})
    end

  end

end
```

This test was running fine before I added some more test for user and roles.

### More test I added

Here are the instructions I followed:

- I added this to Gemfile: `gem 'devise'`
- In `config/environments/development.rb`, added some default mailer options, `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000' }`.
- Gave config.routes.rb a root route—for example, by adding root to:
  "projects#index".
- Added following to `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Gatherer</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track':
       'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

    <%= javascript_pack_tag "projects" %>
  </head>

  <body>
  
  <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
  <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
  <%= yield %>

  </body>
</html>
```

- added following to `app/models/user.rb`:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
:recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

- added following to `spec/support/devise.rb`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :view
config.include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers, type: :system
config.include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers, type: :request
end
```

- added following to `test/test_helper.rb`:

```
module ActionController
  class TestCase
    include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers
  end
end

module ActionDispatch
  class IntegrationTest
    include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers
  end
end
```

- added this test to `spec/system/user_and_role_spec.rb`:

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe "with users and roles" do

    def log_in_as(user)
        visit new_user_session_path
        fill_in("user_email", with: user.email)
        fill_in("user_password", with: user.password)
        click_button("Log in")
    end

    let(:user) { User.create(email: "test@example.com", password: "password") }

    it "allows a logged-in user to view the project index page" do
        log_in_as(user)
        visit(projects_path)
        expect(current_path).to eq(projects_path)
    end

    it "does not allow a user to see the project page if not logged in" do
        visit(projects_path)
        expect(current_path).to eq(user_session_path)
    end

end
```

- to make the test pass I added this to `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`:

```
module ActionController
  class TestCase
    include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers
  end
end

module ActionDispatch
  class IntegrationTest
    include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers
  end
end
```

- Here's the `app/controllers/application_contoller.rb` file:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```

### Error

After running the command `bundle exec rspec`, I'm getting the following error:

```
1) ProjectsController create calls the workflow with parameters
     Failure/Error:
       expect(CreatesProject).to have_received(:new)
         .with({name: "Runway", task_string: "start something:2"})
     
       (CreatesProject (class)).new({:name=>"Runway", :task_string=>"start something:2"})
           expected: 1 time with arguments: ({:name=>"Runway", :task_string=>"start something:2"})
           received: 0 times
     # ./spec/controllers/projects_controller_spec.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What did you try so far to debug this?

Comment: @Kielstra Can you guide me on how to debug the code? I'm a newbie. If you can help me, that would be great.

Comment: You code has no issue, test case is perfect and also controller, please share your route and what about your other tests all are green?

Comment: @KamalPanhwar I added some other test too because of them I started getting this error. Should I share those files too?

Comment: sure you can share I can check them, as above all are correct.

Comment: @KamalPanhwar Can you please check now? I added some more files.

Comment: what is result of `rspec spec/workflows/creates_project_spec.rb` command?

Comment: @KamalPanhwar all test passes

Comment: @KamalPanhwar sorry I added wrong code to `spec/system/user_and_role.rb` file. Can you please give it a check again?

Answer (score 0):

When you added code of authentication, that mean now all your controlle require user to be logged in. Make sure you have `spec/support/devise.rb` file with following contentn

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :view
  config.include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers, type: :system
  config.include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers, type: :request
end
```

Now add two lines one for `user` creation and another to sign_in user in your test case, now you complete test `spec/controllers/projects_controller_spec.rb` will have following content

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ProjectsController, type: :controller do
  describe 'create' do
    let(:user) { User.create(email: 'test@example.com', password: 'password') }
    it 'calls the workflow with parameters' do
      sign_in(user)
      workflow = instance_spy(CreatesProject, success?: true)
      allow(CreatesProject).to receive(:new).and_return(workflow)
      post :create,
      params: { project: { name: "Runway", tasks: "start something:2" } }
      expect(CreatesProject).to have_received(:new)
        .with(name: 'Runway', task_string: 'start something:2')
    end
  end
end
```

Note: Chapter 13: Testing for Security explains everything about this, even it goes further by binding projects with roles and user, so you should read it twice to understand all this and why it is giving your errors, as further you go need to add more changes for role, and workflow.

Comment: Still cannot resolve the issue :( If you need more files do let me know. I'm facing this issue for quite a while now but don't know how to resolve it :(

Comment: well share applciation_controller

Comment: Can please check it now? I have shared the file.

Comment: So from your application_controller solution of issue is given in my answer you need to try it out. `before_action :authenticate_user!` is making your controller authenticated, but your test does not, so you have to use suggested solution to do it. If you want to sure just comment `# before_action :authenticate_user!` line and your test will pass. Check above solution you may be doing something wrong.

Comment: Now I'm getting the different error:  ```Failure/Error: expect(current_path).to eq(user_session_path)
     
       expected: "/users/sign_in"
            got: "/projects"
     
       (compared using ==)```

Comment: This is normal you have removed line of authentication and your test has that if someone visits `/projects` then it should redirect to `/users/sign_in` but it won't as you removed line so it is telling you that it is redirecting to `/projects` I updated above answer please try out and don't comment line of `before_action :authenticate_user!`

Comment: I have updated answer, please remove previous answers codes and try this. it will work.

Comment: Now I'm facing the different issue: ```An error occurred while loading ./spec/workflows/creates_project_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)```

Comment: Error seem you either forget `require 'rails_helper'` or you have changed something `config/applications.rb` The error mean it could not find a file someone in your test cases.